# pass form field value to new (dynamic) page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, variables, post

I'm trying to pass a value from an input field to other pages. 
Unfortunately the value is not retrieving/not working, so hopefully someone could help me with this.

**page.php**

```
<form action="" id="testform" method="post">          
    <select size="1" class="dropdown">
        <?php // dropdown options (pages)
        $Args = array ('cat' => 1);
        $loop = new WP_Query( $Args );
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>          
           <option value="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
           </option>     
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>    
    <input id="year" name="year" type="text" value=""/><!--The value that will be passed to another page -->
    <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="ENTER"/>   
</form>
```

**On submit** - go to location (form action)

```
    $(".button").click(function(){   
        var linkadress = $('.dropdown option:selected').val();
        window.location = linkadress;
        return false;
    });
```

**Footer.php**

**THE PROBLEM:** passing the value (field id = year )

```
var yearfield = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']); ?>";
alert(yearfield); // Currently no value is passed
```

Build on `wordpress platform`. The form is visible on all the pages. When the form is sumbitted the `'year'` value should be retrieved on the new page (the chosen dropdown location). The rest of the code is working fine.

Comment: why not use submit it normally, because right now, you're not actually `POST`ing it. its a simple redirect. or just pass it as a url query string and use `$_GET` instead

Comment: i think the form is not submit. you just reload your page

Comment: You are not submitting the form then how/why it will be available?

Comment: I would like visitors to select a category page from the (dynamic filled) dropdown upon which the page redirects to the prefered page. (working) the value from year I would like to print on the page they chose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not submitting (posting) the form, you are redirecting when you click the button. So PHP never receives the $_POST.

Either you have to have to use `submit()` in your function, or you have to add the year-variable to the url.

```
$(".button").click(function(){   
        var linkadress = $('.dropdown').val();
        $("#testform").setAttribute('action', 'linkadress');
        $("#testform").submit();
        //Now you can use $_POST['year'] in linkadress
        return false;
    });
```

or

```
$(".button").click(function(){   
        var linkadress = $('.dropdown option:selected').val();
        var year = $().val('#year'); 
        window.location = linkadress + '?year=' + year;
        //Now you can use $_GET['year'] in linkadress
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used to submit version. It looks better front-end wise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the value of **select** not **option**. (Also it is better to set an ID for  select and use jquery ID selector instead of class selector.)

```
 $(".button").click(function(){   
        var linkadress = $('.dropdown').val();
        window.location = linkadress;
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I will edit to javascript. Any idea how I would pass the year value to the page (linkadress)?

Comment: yes. You can also retrieve value of year using $("#year").val() and add it to linkaddress as querystring before doing any action. e.g. **var linkaddress=$(".dropdown").val()+"?year="+$("#year").val();** and get in in the next page using **$_GET["year"];**

Comment: Thank you foor helping! I've used the submit version from Michel witouth url sabotaging.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to change the form action based on the value of the drop down, 
if so then;

```
$("#testform").submit(function(){   
    var linkadress = $('.dropdown option:selected').val();
    $(this).attr('action', linkadress);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will edit to javascript. Any idea how I would pass the year value to the page (linkadress)?

Comment: This should post the entire form to the location defined in the form's action so it should be accessible via $_POST['year']. With the code above you will no longer need the button click event as it will not post the form due to the 'window.location' and 'return false'

Comment: Thank you foor helping! I've used the submit version from Michel witouth url sabotaging.